# Memory leak with xmlCopyNode (libxml2)?

Tags: c, xml, memory, memory-leaks, libxml2

I am extracting information from an xml file using libxml2 on C/Linux. I made a function that looks for the first occurrence of a certain tag and returns a *copy* of this tag.

For example given the following xml text:

```
<a><b>First occurrence of tag b<c>Child node</c></b><b>Second occurrence of tag b</b></a>
```

I want to extract the first  tag, with all children if present.

Here is a strapped-down version of the code I use:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <libxml/parser.h>
#include <libxml/tree.h>

#ifdef LIBXML_TREE_ENABLED

static int
xml_extract_first_occurrence_by_name(xmlNode * start_node, xmlNode * first_occurrence, xmlChar * node_name)
{    
    xmlNode *cur_node = NULL;

    for (cur_node = start_node; cur_node; cur_node = cur_node->next) {
        if ( !xmlStrcmp(cur_node->name, node_name) ) {
            // use libxml2 function xmlCopyNode to recursively copy cur_node (i.e. copy node + children) to first_occurrence
            // (since cur_node will not be valid outside this function)
            *first_occurrence = *xmlCopyNode(cur_node, 1);
            return 1;
        }

        // if not found in parent search recursively in children
        if (cur_node->children)
            if ( xml_extract_first_occurrence_by_name(cur_node->children, first_occurrence, node_name) )
                return 1;
    }
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    xmlDoc *doc = NULL;
    xmlNode *root_element = NULL;

    if (argc != 2)
        return(1);

    // initialize libxml2 and check for version mismatches
    LIBXML_TEST_VERSION

    /*parse the file and get the DOM */
    doc = xmlReadFile(argv[1], NULL, XML_PARSE_NOBLANKS);

    /*Get the root element node */
    root_element = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);

    // allocate memory for the node to be extracted (including up to 10 children)
    xmlNode *first_occurrence = malloc(11 * sizeof(xmlNode));

    // search in tag root_element the first occurrence of tag "b"
    xml_extract_first_occurrence_by_name(root_element, first_occurrence, "b");

    printf("\nFirst occurrence of tag b -> Text content: %s\n", first_occurrence->children->content);
    printf("\nFirst occurrence of tag b -> Child tag: %s\n", first_occurrence->children->next->name);
    printf("\nFirst occurrence of tag b -> Child tag text content: %s\n", first_occurrence->children->next->children->content);

    free(first_occurrence);

    /*free the document */
    xmlFreeDoc(doc);

    /*
     *Free the global variables that may
     *have been allocated by the parser.
     */
    xmlCleanupParser();

    return 0;
}
#else
int main(void) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Tree support not compiled in\n");
    exit(1);
}
#endif
```

The program runs as expected and there are also no compiler warnings. If I run it through valgrind though (with enabled leak-check) I get errors.

```
valgrind --leak-check=full ./first-occurrence-test.bin first-occurrence-test.xml
==18986== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==18986== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==18986== Using Valgrind-3.10.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==18986== Command: ./first-occurrence-test.bin first-occurrence-test.xml
==18986== 

First occurrence of tag b -> Text content: First occurrence of tag b

First occurrence of tag b -> Child tag: c

First occurrence of tag b -> Child tag text content: Child node
==18986== 
==18986== HEAP SUMMARY:
==18986==     in use at exit: 281 bytes in 8 blocks
==18986==   total heap usage: 77 allocs, 69 frees, 47,465 bytes allocated
==18986== 
==18986== 281 (60 direct, 221 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 7 of 7
==18986==    at 0x402A17C: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==18986==    by 0x409A01E: ??? (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.9.1)
==18986==    by 0x80487C0: xml_extract_first_occurrence_by_name (first-occurrence-test.c:30)
==18986==    by 0x8048848: xml_extract_first_occurrence_by_name (first-occurrence-test.c:36)
==18986==    by 0x80488FD: main (first-occurrence-test.c:63)
==18986== 
==18986== LEAK SUMMARY:
==18986==    definitely lost: 60 bytes in 1 blocks
==18986==    indirectly lost: 221 bytes in 7 blocks
==18986==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==18986==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==18986==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==18986== 
==18986== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==18986== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

I tried removing the function and doing everything in main. Same result.

Am I overseeing something? Is this a possible issue (or something I don't know) with xmlCopyNode? Or a false positive?

Thanks for any help or comment.

EDIT: I got it to work, the key was acknowledging that xmlCopyNode() already allocates memory (no need to allocate again) and using `xmlFreeNode()` to free memory allocated by xmlCopyNode(). Thank you both for your answers.

Answer (score 3):

```
given that C passes by value, not by reference,
to change where a pointer points to,
a sub function needs the address of the actual pointer
therefore:

this line: 
*first_occurrence = *xmlCopyNode(cur_node, 1);
has a few problems:
Below is what needs to be done to correct the problems
and eliminate the memory leak

-------------
note that:
the xmlCopyNode returns a pointer to a a copy of the original node.
I.E. it returns a pointer, that must be (eventually) passed to some form of free()
-------------

Note: the passed parameter: 'first_occurrence'
is already pointing to an allocated memory area via:
(this is where the leak starts)
xmlNode *first_occurrence = malloc(11 * sizeof(xmlNode));

-------------
suggest changing this line:
*first_occurrence = *xmlCopyNode(cur_node, 1);

to :
*first_occurrence = xmlCopyNode(cur_node, 1);

-------------

then remove the malloc so this line:
xmlNode *first_occurrence = malloc(11 * sizeof(xmlNode));

becomes:
xmlNode *first_occurrence = NULL;

-------------

finally change this line so the parameter contains the address of
rather than the contents of first_occurrence
xml_extract_first_occurrence_by_name(root_element, first_occurrence, "b");

to this:
xml_extract_first_occurrence_by_name(root_element, &first_occurrence, "b");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I see the reasoning behind your suggestions, i.e. as xmlCopyNode already allocates memory for the copy we make sure we use that memory rather than allocating more. So I went on with your changes, though I had to also change the type of first_occurrence in the function declaration to pointer of pointer `xmlNode ** first_occurrence`, that makes sense to me. Still the leak is there. Please note I also removed `free(first_occurrence)` as we don't explicitly malloc it anymore. Instead I'd expect libxml2 to free this memory through its cleanup routines, am I wrong here?

Comment: As I said in my other comment I got it to work now by freeing libxml2 allocated memory with `xmlFreeNode(first_occurrence);`.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend to you would use

```
xmlNode *  -> xmlNodePtr
```

because why that's already typedef of ptr type.
And xmlCopyNode() function returns already memory alloced. 
So, You don't need to malloc on first_occurence::

Important modifying points are like this ::

```
xmlNode *first_occurrence, -> xmlNodePtr first_occurrence,
```

And following function prototype will be modified , using the pointer to pointer on first_occurrence

```
static int xml_extract_first_occurrence_by_name(xmlNodePtr start_node, xmlNodePtr *first_occurrence, xmlChar * node_name)
{    
    xmlNodePtr cur_node = NULL;
```

following copy first_occurence will be followings::

```
            *first_occurrence = xmlCopyNode(cur_node, 1);
            return 1;
        }
```

And Main body ::

```
xmlDoc *doc  -> xmlDocPtr doc = NULL;
xmlNode *root_element   -> xmlNodePtr  root_element = NULL;



    // allocate memory for the node to be extracted (including up to 10 children)
    // xmlNode *first_occurrence = malloc(11 * sizeof(xmlNode));
    // -> 
    xmlNodePtr first_occurrence = NULL;

    // search in tag root_element the first occurrence of tag "b"
    xml_extract_first_occurrence_by_name(root_element, &first_occurrence, "b");
```

Also You need to use xmlNodeFree()

```
    // free(first_occurrence); 
    xmlFreeNode(first_occurrence);
```

It's paired coding using libxml2 .

Comment: That `xmlFreeNode(first_occurrence);` did it! As I was saying in my comment to @user3629249 just now I'd expect a libxml2 function to free memory allocated by a libxml2 function. And this is the function `xmlFreeNode()`(also adequately named). Yes the prototype change I'd already made it to reflect the other changes. As for xmlNode* vs. xmlNodePtr I've read contrasting opinions as to which one to use. Anyhow it is only a formal matter.